# How to know the client domain in a http request

Tags: http, go, request, client-server

I am making an API for an app (using golang) that will be consumed by different clients. I would know if there is any way to know the domain of the client that is doing the request.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Client domain is not sent as part of an HTTP request, but client IP is.

Answer (score 3):

The [`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) contains a `RemoteAddr` field which should provide the information you seek.

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy I will try.

Answer (score 1):

you can get it in `RemoteAddr string` field in [http.Request](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request)

> RemoteAddr allows HTTP servers and other software to record the
>   network address that sent the request, usually for logging. This field
>   is not filled in by ReadRequest and has no defined format. The HTTP
>   server in this package sets RemoteAddr to an "IP:port" address before
>   invoking a handler.

This field is ignored by the HTTP client